# Can generic pointers be resolved without casting?

Tags: c

I have two very large structure. Both have few fields common amongst them but also have unique fields. What I am trying to do is copy content of these common fields to a third structure based on a certain condition which structure to copy. Now here comes the main problem. I don't want to write two different functions for copying. Like for example

```
    struct test1 {
    //Has many members
    } TEST1_INFO;

    TEST1_INFO  *g_TEST1_ptr;

    struct test2 {
    //Has many members
    } TEST2_INFO;

    TEST2_INFO  *g_TEST2_ptr;

    struct destination_struct {
    //Has many members
    } DEST_INFO;

    DEST_INFO  *g_DEST_ptr;
```

One way of copying content from either structure 1 or 2 would be to write two different copying functions and call the one required, this is what I want to avoid. Other would be to put conditions in a single functions and copy content from desired of the two structure which is another way of implementing the previous technique.

What I want is something like this:

```
    void * generic_pointer;
    if(//mycondition)
        generic_pointer = g_TEST1_ptr;
    else
        generic_pointer = g_TEST2_ptr;

    g_DEST_ptr->member1 = generic_pointer->member1; ...
```

Is this possible??? Or is there some alternate solution for what I am trying to acheive? Please note this is specific to ANSI-C...

EDIT 1:
Okay so while exploring for possible alternate solutions I came across this union which I have not ever used previously can someone please tell me if a union can be used to resolve my problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Since `test1` and `test2` are in no way related, the best approach IMO would be to have separate functions for each copy operation.

Comment: Of course, not. Offset for `generic_pointer->member1` must be calc'd at compile time.

Comment: @HappyCoder thats the thing my structure are like huge and I want to avoid repeating same code if I can avoid it.

Comment: If you declare all the common fields first, that would make copying easier. Or, have a nested `struct` which contains all the common fields.

Comment: What about putting the common fields in a separate structure, and then including it in `test1` and `test2`?

Comment: @HappyCoder and I think alike. That way, all the fields may be copied with a single instruction.

Comment: @WeatherVane I can't edit the structures that would be a disaster for the whole system. There structure are basically data maps for the whole system to use. Any change in them would mean editing thousands of files of code. But I like your approach.

Comment: @WeatherVane and so do many others (given the answers) ;)

Comment: Its the "god-structure" syndrome. Yet, please consider, that the more code depends on those structures, the higher the risk to pull some tricks like risky recasting etc. Maybe, in the long run, you can see that some parts of the code base only use the common part, while other parts only need 1 or the other version. Then you learned something about the system and changing the types will pay off.

Comment: @BitTickler Thank you! Can you see my latest edit and help with that?

Comment: @UsamaZafar I consider "thousands" of lines of code still quite small *laughs*

Comment: @BitTickler Its thousands of files each over thousands of lines of code. :D

Comment: In that case, there is another option: Create a function- API and decouple all those thousands of code files from the type. Have them query what they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible the way you describe it.  The only way a void pointer can be dereferenced is by converting it to another type first.

As to how you mighty go about doing what you want, it depends on what you mean by "common fields".

If your meaning is a set of members with the same name AND the same type, the solution is simple.

```
   struct CommonToBoth
   {
       /*  list all the members in common to both your structs */
   };

  struct test1
  {
      struct CommonToBoth common;

        /*  other members specific to test1 here */
  };

  struct test2
  {
       struct CommonToBoth common;

        /*  other members specific to test2 here */
  };
```

From there, the way to copy the common parts is simple, if all you need is a shallow copy (copy by value).

```
  struct test1 x;
  struct test2 y;

    /*  initialise x */

  y.common = x.common;   /* this copies all the common parts by value */
```

That allows you to tease out common operations into functions as needed.   If you need a deep copy for any common parts (e.g. one member is a pointer which must be dynamically allocated on copying) then you will need to write a function to copy the common parts, not just copy by value.

You can also place the parts specific to each of your `struct` types into other `struct` types if needed.   That depends on whether you intend to reuse those parts in other `struct` types.   So you could do

```
  struct test1 x;
  struct test2 y;
     /* initialise */

  x.common = y.common;
  x.specific = some_other_x.specific;
  y.specific = some_other_y.specific;
  x.specific = y.specific;    /* this will have a type mismatch, so compiler error */
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer can you please take a look at my latest edit and comment on that?

Comment: There are some specific forms of your problem where a union might help.   But, there are also variants where a union would cause more trouble than help.   So, generally speaking, I would recommend against using a union.   Work on understanding now normal structs operate first.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-structure your structures like this: Build a structure with the common fields and use it for the 2 structures you want. Then build 2 structures for the different fields. This allows you to write fewer lines of code for transfering. After all, you have no way of avoiding the question about what to do with the fields which differ.

```
struct common_tag { /* common fields */ };
struct flavor1_specifics_tag { /* fields, specific to flavor1 */ };
struct flavor2_specifics_tag { /* fields, specific to flavor2 */ };
struct flavor1_tag { struct common_tag common; struct flavor1_specifics_tag others; };
struct flavor2_tag { struct common_tag common; struct flavor2_specifics_tag others; };
```

With that in place, you can use the 2 structs in polymorphic ways. At least to bits:

```
struct common_tag *flavor1_to_common( struct flavor1_tag * f1 );
struct common_tag *flavor2_to_common( struct flavor2_tag * f2 );
```

You also avoid nasty surprises in the future, when you or someone else modifies the structures, unaware that you try to (ab)use the commonalities. With the strategy shown here, it is rather obvious what you want to do and future changes will less likely blow up by shortcuts you would otherwise take.